# Как с помощью DownloadManager загрузить файл, размер у которого заранее неизвестен?

Tags: java, android, download, manager

Есть следующий код, который работает при скачивании файлов с заранее известным размером (выполняется внутри AsyncTask):

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urls[0]));
    request.setDescription(filename);
    request.setTitle("Загрузка: " + filename);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Download", filename);

    return String.valueOf(((DownloadManager) c.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request));
```

Что нужно сюда дописать, чтобы этот же код скачивал файлы с заранее неизвестным размером? Я пытаюсь скачать видео flv.

Comment: Где в этом коде "заранее известный размер"? Вывод: дело не в размере. Если имеется в виду ютуб и т.п., то класс `DownloadManager` вряд ли вам поможет - там видео отдаётся хитрым способом.

Comment: У меня просто есть ссылка на загрузку отрезка видео с видеорегистраторов двух разных производителей. Если загружать браузером видео по этим ссылкам, разница в загрузках в том, что на одном видеорегистраторе заранее известна длина файла при загрузке (соответственно в браузере отображаются проценты загрузки), а на другом регистраторе - загрузка идет просто, без процентов. Когда я скармливаю обе ссылки DownloadManager, в первом случае он работает, а во втором - постоянно вываливает ошибку.

Comment: DownloadManager - это такая "вещь в себе". Размер видео, насколько я понимаю, проверяется где-то внутри DownloadManager перед началом загрузки, как он там устроен - я не вникал. Факт в том, что разница между рабочей и нерабочей загрузками именно в отсутствии заранее известного размера. Решил проблему костылем: написал свой собственный класс для загрузки файлов через HttpURLConnection и Input/OutputStream, который работает в обоих случаях, осталось только привязать к моему классу BroadcastReceiver при окончании загрузки. DownloadManager там в принципе не используется.

Comment: Но мне все равно интересно узнать решение этой проблемы с использованием DownloadManager

Answer (score 0):

```
final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
final int length = connection.getContentLength();
```

Но это только в том случае если сервер выдает ContentLength

Comment: В том и проблема, что когда сервер выдает длину файла - работает мой код из примера. А что делать, если нет?

Comment: Тогда нет больше вариантов, даже если вы скачиваете через Chrome файл из подобного сервера то тоже не показывает вес файла

Comment: Мне не нужно узнавать размер файла, мне нужно заставить стандартный DownloadManager в Android работать с такими загрузками.

Comment: это не возможно, если бы это было возможно chrome бы это уже реализовал

Comment: И chrome тут вообще не при чем, потому что там все работает, проблема в моем приложении.

Comment: А у Chrome свой загрузчик или он использует тот же системный? Если второе, то значит проблема решаема. Но экстрасенсорных способностей нам не хватит, что бы понять как. Рассмотрите внимательно логи, сравните чем ещё отличаются источники, запросы и ответы. Попробуйте так же поиграться с настройками запроса в плане сети (`setAllowedNetworkTypes(int flags)` и т.д.) - единственное что приходит на ум, что может отклонить (или скорее отложить) загрузку из-за 'Content-Length', это ограничения по мобильному траффику. И, кстати, через Wi-Fi и моб. сеть одинаково не работает?

Comment: Насчет загрузчика в мобильном Chrome - я позже протестирую и напишу, я на десктопном хроме ссылки тестировал. С настройками запроса я тоже пробовал играться, без особого успеха. Еще, кстати, тестировал код на планшете, где вообще нет мобильной сети, только WiFi, поэтому навряд ли это могли быть ограничения мобильного трафика. Параметры запроса и заголовки я тоже указывал точно такие же (смотрел в консоли разработчика на пекарне), безрезультатно.

Comment: Да, загрузка этого видео работает даже в мобильной версии Chrome. Используется такой же загрузчик, системный. Только там в DownloadManager отображается размер (сколько скачано МБ из ?), поэтому загрузка таких видосов в системном загрузчике каким-то образом все-таки реализуема.